# Android notification rebuilds instead of updating?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm downloading a file and i want to keep the user informed about the progress so i created a notification.The problem is that the notification keeps getting rebuild instead of updating. I searched for similar behaviours online and i did as they said but my problem persists.

Everybody is saying to use a notification builder so the first time it builds the whole notification and then only updates what i tell it to.Tried it,still not working.

Here i'm declaring the notification and the notificationManager.

```
private NotificationCompat.Builder notification;
private NotificationManager notificationManager;
```

This is the method that creates the notification.DOWNLOAD_NOTIFICATION_ID is a final int with value 2

```
private void createDownloadNotification(){

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(GuideSelected.this.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(GuideSelected.this,CHANNEL_DOWNLOAD)
                    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download)  // here is the animated icon
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download))
                    .setContentTitle("title")
                    .setContentText("Download starting...")
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle())

                    //.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    //la notifica si cancella da sola dopo che clicco
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
                    .setProgress(100,0,false);
            notificationManager.notify(DOWNLOAD_NOTIFICATION_ID,notification.build());
        }
}
```

This is the asynctask where i'm updating the notification

```
private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
            int count;
           // HERE I'M CREATING THE NOTIFICATION
                createDownloadNotification();

        //DOWNLOADING STUFF....

        }

        // Updating progress bar

        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {

            // UPDATING IT EVERY 5% SO I DON't MAKE TOO MANY CALLS

            currentPercentage=Integer.parseInt(progress[0]);

                if (previousPercentage != currentPercentage && currentPercentage%5==0) {// line : 6
                    notification.setProgress(100,previousPercentage, false).setContentText(previousPercentage+"%").setSubText("Downloading...");
                    notificationManager.notify(DOWNLOAD_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification.build());
                    previousPercentage=currentPercentage;
                }

        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String message) {

            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    notification.setProgress(0,0,false).setOngoing(false).setContentText("Download complete").setSubText(null);
                    notificationManager.notify(DOWNLOAD_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification.build());
                }
            }, 2000);


        }
    }
```

I just want the notification to update without rebuilding everytime, i can see it rebuilds from the animated download icon because it keeps restarting.

EDIT:
Added the declaration of notification and notification manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i solved it by using custom download intent service class which extends [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService) and when i'm updating the notification i'm controlling if the last % is different than the current one (since the updateProgress is called multiple times in a second) and i also added a timer so it only updates every 1.3 seconds (this is the time that the download icon aniamtion takes to complete) and in this way i finally achieved my goal and the notification doesn't continuously rebuild.

Here is how i'm updating the notification:

```
   while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                if (Constants.stopService) {
                    output.flush();
                    output.close();
                    input.close();
                    stopSelf();
                    return;
                }
                if (count != 0) {
                    total += count;

                    latestPercentDone = (int) Math.round(total / lengthOfFile * 100.0);
                    if (percentDone != latestPercentDone) {
                        percentDone = latestPercentDone;
                        if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime > 1300) { // 1000 = 1second
                            mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                            sendMessage(percentDone, idLesson);
                            notification.setProgress(100, percentDone, false);
                            notificationManager.notify(realNotificationID, notification.build());
                        }
                    }
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }
            }
            // flushing output
            output.flush();
            // closing streams
            output.close();
            input.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#Updating

> To update this notification after you've issued it, call NotificationManagerCompat.notify() again, passing it a notification with the same ID you used previously. If the previous notification has been dismissed, a new notification is created instead.
>
> You can optionally call setOnlyAlertOnce() so your notification interupts the user (with sound, vibration, or visual clues) only the first time the notification appears and not for later updates.

```
        notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(GuideSelected.this,CHANNEL_DOWNLOAD)
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download)  // here is the animated icon
                .setContentTitle("title")
                .setContentText("Download starting...")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW);
        notificationManager.notify(DOWNLOAD_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification.build());
```

Should work to keep updating the same notification, once you have this working, I would then add back the other settings you had on the builder (such a bigIcon etc, too see if adding one of those is breaking it.)

Comment: Just tried this, the notification is still being rebuilt everytime. Also tried changing the DOWNLOAD_NOTIFICATION_ID with another value and it still isn't working...

Comment: then there is either some code running doing something else, or it's a device specific problem, try another device/emulator

Comment: I tried it on a Huawei View 10 Lite(API 28) and on a Samsung Galaxy S6(API 24) and it happens in both of them. As for some other code running...i don't know,i'd say i don't think so because the snippet above is the only place where i'm using a notificationManager and a notification...(apart from the Application class where i'm creating the download channel for API 26+).

Comment: What i don't really understand is why should i use "notification.build()" when i'm updating the notification. Doesn't this create a new notification with all the params that i specified in the "createDownloadNotification()" method? I know that it should only update the params that i'm changing in "onProgressUpdate()", but if you ask me i think it first takes all the params from the "createDownloadNotification()", then adds the new ones and then recreates/ updates the whole notification since it basically  has to change all params.

Comment: The documentation says you only need the ID, you should delete as much code as possible until you get it working (as shown in the docs), then add to it a bit at a time until you find out what is causing the problem.

Comment: Well i literally only had icon,title,text and priority left and it still didn't work. I don't really know what else i can do.

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity

```
private NotificationCompat.Builder notification;
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;

    int DOWNLOAD_NOTIFICATION_ID = 232;
 private void createDownloadNotification(){


        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(MainActivity.this.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this,"download")
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download)  // here is the animated icon
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download))
                .setContentTitle("title")
                .setContentText("Download starting...")
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle())

                //.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                //la notifica si cancella da sola dopo che clicco
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
                .setProgress(100,0,false);
        notificationManager.notify(DOWNLOAD_NOTIFICATION_ID,notification.build());
    }
```

now in your AsyncTask use it like

```
  class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    int currentPercentage;
    int previousPercentage;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        createDownloadNotification();
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url)
    {
        // Dummy code for notificaion progress you can change it with download file logic.
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(50);
                publishProgress(i + ""); //publish the progress to update the progress of Notification.
            } catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress)
    {
        // UPDATING IT EVERY 5% SO I DON't MAKE TOO MANY CALLS
        currentPercentage = Integer.parseInt(progress[0]);

        if (previousPercentage != currentPercentage && currentPercentage % 5 == 0)
        {// line : 6
            notification.setProgress(100, previousPercentage, false).setContentText(previousPercentage + "%").setSubText("Downloading...");
            notificationManager.notify(DOWNLOAD_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification.build());
            previousPercentage = currentPercentage;
        }

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String message)
    {
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                notification.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download_done); //update the icon 
                notification.setProgress(0, 0, false).setOngoing(false).setContentText("Download complete").setSubText(null);
                notificationManager.notify(DOWNLOAD_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification.build());
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

Create you notification in `PreExecute` method, then in `onBackGround` Method just publish the progress.

Hope this will fix your issue